# How to reload one part of BorderPane after button clicked using fxml in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I am currently working on some GUI using JavaFX and JavaFX Scene Builder. I've met an issue and it is not that easy to find a solution for it (at least for me). I'd would like to get something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b6uG.png

And the point is that after click on the TreeItem "Sample" only the right side of the window will reload. I would like to do it also using fxml files. 
I know that I can include one fxml in another but that's not the solution. There might be a lot of TreeItems, and every TreeItem should load another pane configured by another FXML. 
Can you guys at least steer me on the good track, please?

(Sorry the image is in link but I do not have 10 reps yet as I'm new here...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to load the node and setting the node on the right?

```
Node root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("fxml/yourfxml.fxml"));
borderPane.setRight(root);
```

Comment: Was the border pane initialized?